# Difficulty refactoring a graphics point from displaying a tooltip to a label when using show to combine point with a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, linear-algebra, tooltip, labeled

I have a `Plot[...]` of a system of linear equations and a function `graphicsPoint[...]` that generates a graphics point to show where the lines intersect. The `Tooltip[...]` version of `graphicsPoint[...]` at the intersection point works but a `Labeled[...]` version is preferred which should be placed next to but above the graphics point.

I am aware of using `Callout[...]` but this is not preferred because it needs to wrap one of the equations which are generated by another function and would greatly complicate the code for that function. However if I am misunderstanding it's use and can be done without wrapping one of the equations I am open to it.

Below are two versions of the `graphicsPoint[...]`.

Here is the desired plot of system of two linear equations. This works...

```
plot = Plot[{(1 - x)/2, -2 - 3 x}, {x, -3, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLabels -> {y == (1 - x)/2, y == -2 - 3 x}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}]
```

This tooltip version of `graphicsPoint[...]` works alone and when combined with `plot=Plot[...]` using `Show[plot,graphicsPoint[...]]`...

```
graphicsPoint[loc_ : {0, 0}, color_ : Red, size_ : 8] := 
  Block[{graphic},
   graphic = If[Length[loc] == 2, Graphics, Graphics3D];
   graphic[{
     color, AbsolutePointSize[size], Tooltip[
      Point[loc], loc, 
      TooltipStyle -> {22, Black, Background -> LightBlue}
      ]
     }]];
graphicsPoint[{-1, 3}]
Show[plot, graphicsPoint[{-1, 3}]]
```

`graphicsPoint2[...]` is the attempted refactor of said graphics point replacing `Tooltip[...]` with `Labeled[...]`. It only halfway works alone as it does label the point but far below it at the very bottom of the bounding box rendering it almost useless. It creates an error when combined using `Show` Also note that the `BaseStyle` for `Labeled[...,BaseStyle]` is mostly ignored by Mathematica...

```
graphicsPoint2[loc_ : {0, 0}, color_ : Red, size_ : 8] := Block[{fn},
   fn = If[Length[loc] == 2, Graphics, Graphics3D];
   Labeled[
    fn[{
      color,
      AbsolutePointSize[size],
      Point[loc]
      }
     ],
    loc, BaseStyle -> {22, Black, Background -> LightBlue}]
   ];

graphicsPoint2[{-1, 3}]
Show[plot, graphicsPoint2[{-1, 3}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html), use [`Text`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"];

eqns = {(1 - x)/2, -2 - 3 x};

pt = {x, eqns[[1]]} /.
  Solve[Equal @@ eqns, x, Reals][[1]]

(* {-1, 1} *)

plot = Plot[eqns, {x, -3, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   PlotLabels -> {y == (1 - x)/2, y == -2 - 3 x}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
   ImageSize -> {Automatic, 200}];

graphicsPoint[loc_ : {0, 0}, color_ : Red, size_ : 8] :=
  Block[{graphic},
   graphic = If[Length[loc] == 2, Graphics, Graphics3D];
   graphic[{
     Text[loc, loc, {-1.5, -2}],
     color,
     AbsolutePointSize[size],
     Tooltip[Point[loc], loc,
      TooltipStyle -> {22, Black, Background -> LightBlue}]}]];

Show[plot, graphicsPoint[pt]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. It looks like you had to manually (by trial and error I suppose) derive location `{-1.5, -2}` for text: `Text[loc, loc, {-1.5, -2}]`. I was hoping to avoid that. That is why I was hoping to use a function similar to `Tooltip` that automatically locates the label near the point of interest and includes special options (like `Top`) that refines location.